# My UPDATED content ONLY shows when I am signed in.

Tags: content

Good Day, as mentioned in my title, my webpage Lasnersport.com only shows it's updated content when i am signed in. When not signed in it shows context from months ago  as its current.

Comment: Are you using any caching plugins that may be keeping an old version of the page on the live side?

Answer (score 0):

You are using WP Super Cache. This is serving a page that was generated on January 30. You need to flush your cache, and configure Super Cache correctly, so as to automatically flush when the home page is updated.

Comment: 13 seconds faster :D

Comment: Curses........!

Answer (score 0):

Your Homepage is cached via WP-Super-Cache.

Adjust the settings in the Plugin's options, as we can see here your Cache has been built on January 30th for the last time:

```
<!-- Dynamic page generated in 0.539 seconds. -->
<!-- Cached page generated by WP-Super-Cache on 2013-01-30 14:16:20 -->
<!-- Compression = gzip -->
```

If you deactivate the Plugin, it should also wrk for you.